# Vim-plug installation on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: 16.10, vim, plugins

I'm a new user of Ubuntu, and I'd like a little bit of help with plugins. According to this [website](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug), I installed `vim-plug` with `curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim` command. I have also created the directory `~/.vim/plugged` as suggested. 
So far I know I have to install my plugins inside (in `~/.vimrc` file):

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

call plug#end()
```

It is indicated I have to make the content of "Download plug.vim" available inside the 'autoload' directory.

**Question 1:** What is the 'autoload' directory here?

In fact, I want to install `vim-plug` to install several plugins like `nerdtree`. The way I understand the procedure is to go over the website https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree, and take only the part `scrooloose/nerdtree` to install the plugin :

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'

call plug#end()
```

then execute `:PlugInstall`.

**Question 2:** Could anyone be able to tell me where do I have an issue (if there are)?

Comment: "Could anyone be able to tell me where do I have an issue (if there are)?" That's now how this site works. You identify the issue and ask how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

From [`:h autoload`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#autoload-functions):

```
AUTOMATICALLY LOADING FUNCTIONS 
                                                        autoload-functions
When using many or large functions, it's possible to automatically define them
only when they are used.  There are two methods: with an autocommand and with
the "autoload" directory in 'runtimepath'.

...

Using an autoload script 
                                                        autoload E746
This is introduced in the user manual, section 41.15.

Using a script in the "autoload" directory is simpler, but requires using
exactly the right file name.  A function that can be autoloaded has a name
like this: 

        :call filename#funcname()

When such a function is called, and it is not defined yet, Vim will search the
"autoload" directories in 'runtimepath' for a script file called
"filename.vim".  For example "~/.vim/autoload/filename.vim".  That file should
then define the function like this: 

        function filename#funcname()
           echo "Done!"
        endfunction

The file name and the name used before the # in the function must match
exactly, and the defined function must have the name exactly as it will be
called.
```

So, `autoload` is a directory where you can drop files that define functions, and the file is only read when the function is called for the first time. This makes startup faster.